# Integration of Alexa with Tableau

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, tableau-api

how can Alexa be integrated with a dashboarding tool Tableau. For example, I can pass a voice command via Alexa and it should fetch data from Tableau and read out the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you build a custom Alexa skill which will - roughly speaking - handle the voice commands.
The backend of your skill will then request specific resources from the Tableau REST API (authentication needed of course), process the results and create output speech for Alexa, which contains the relevant information.

Comment: Do we already have such REST API in general or we need to write some custom API for this ?

Comment: Tableau already offers that API: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm

Answer (score 0):

Some people already build an integration of Alexa and Tableau.

[Search  Google for "Alexa Tableau"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Alexa+Tableau)

This link is one example of theseill be helpful to know the possibilities: https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/3/hacking-alexa-and-other-tableau-api-tricks-67108